# We should be able to reply to comments and answers

Tags: discussion, comments

I want to be able to reply to comments and answers directly, instead of having to comment again.

For example, if someone has already answered under a user's answer then I have to write @user. I should just be able to click reply and it adds that for me.

Comment: You already can once you have sufficient rep. Then you can leave comments and @reply. 50 is the limit I think. You currently have 34, so just a little bit more to go.

Comment: How do you want to reply without a comment? chat?

Comment: You can always post comments on your own questions or answers to your own questions regardless of your reputation. **Why** do you want to reply to comments on other people's posts?

Comment: You mean you want a way to directly contact some user?

Answer (score 7):

You use comments to reply to answers... as well as other comments. That's basically how comments work already. I'm not sure what you're getting at otherwise.

If you're talking about threaded comments, no, that's just going to overcomplicate things.

Comment: Threads _always_ complicate things.

Comment: see here if someone has already answered under your answer then I have to do @BoltClock's a Unicorn. I should just be able to click reply and it adds that for me.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow is *not a forum*. Our job is to ask questions and provide answers *to those questions*. That's why comments are small, compact, and ignorable, while questions and answers are big and important. You should avoid attempting to have a long discussion with people. If you're not asking a question, asking for clarification on a question, answering a question, or trying to improve an answer to a question, then your commentary is not needed.

You can effectively reply to a comment using `@` notation, where you say `@<person-name>`, where *<person-name>* is the ID of the person you are talking to. And to "reply" to an answer, you comment on it.

Both of these require having commenting privileges. If you don't have that, then go earn some rep.